# How can I make Azure AD authentication accept an url query string access token

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

Is there a way to configure the built in Azure AD Authentication to accept both an  `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header and an `access_token=<token>` url query string?

I need this to allow a SingalR WebSocket connection from a browser.

**My Scenario**

I have an ASP.Net Core backend hosting SignalR Core hubs. The site is hosted as an Azure App Service with Azure AD Authentication enabled.

Accessing REST Apis works fine, both from a .Net application and from an web site.

**From .Net**

A SignalR connection with a .Net application works fine and uses websocket. The websocket connection is established with the following HTTP request:

```
GET https://<url>/hubs/chat?id=rk-Adzl1EWGCv8wsVF5ayg HTTP/1.1
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Key: m02nzEFDAFVwCgUPlF2rEA==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Host: evotrqhub.evopro-ag.de
Cookie: ARRAffinity=8666c8fbc8cd126e76e2b31c5880dd9c4968a103221108a610b408e12a15fa39
```

Please note that the authorization is done with an `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header.

**From a browser**

When I establish a SignalR connection from a browser (Chrome or Firefox), no websocket connection can be established and long polling is used as fallback. The HTTP request for the websocket connection is:

```
GET https://evotrqhub.evopro-ag.de/hubs/coilthickness?id=QB5xx4MLGi6uSvVK4QmvZA&access_token=<token> HTTP/1.1
Host: evotrqhub.evopro-ag.de
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://localhost:5000
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ARRAffinity=8666c8fbc8cd126e76e2b31c5880dd9c4968a103221108a610b408e12a15fa39
Sec-WebSocket-Key: K4hUR2QFyRxcDKxfoNwn2w==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
```

Here the authorization is done with a `auth_token=<token>` url query parameter.

The response from the server is a redirect (response code 302) to the Azure AD login page.

The [SignalR Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.0) advise to use `JwtBearerEvents` `OnMessageReceived` to handle the situation, but in this case the Azure AD authentication of the Azure Service App rejects the query before it can be handled by my user code.

So is there a way to configure the Azure App Service AD Authentication to accept the `access_token` parameter?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SignalR, but can you check if this will fix your problem? [Authorize Your Azure AD Users With SignalR](https://kwilson.io/blog/authorize-your-azure-ad-users-with-signalr/)

Comment: This will not work in my scenario, since the request is rejected by the Azure Web Site host before the call is routed to my code. But I think I will have to deactivate this Azure Authentication and handle it in my code. Then this approach will work.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't notice that part. So did you use the Authentication/Authorization of App Service, right? In that case, the suggestion will definitely won't work. Is your web app is a Single Page Application? if yes, you can use ADAL.js, but this is a code change in your part. IMHO, I don't think you can configure the built in Azure App Service AD Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I don't known if there is a built in way for manage this with the [Microsoft identity platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/active-directory/develop/) (probably yes), anyway you can simply add a middlware in your pipeline to check if the bearer token exists in the request context, if not, check if exists the *access_token* parameter in the querystring collection and then add it as bearer token in a new authorization header as shown in the below snippet of code.

**Startup.cs**

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        ...  
      
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        // START BEARER TOKEN MIDDLEWARE ---------------------------------------------
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.Request.Headers["Authorization"]) &&
                context.Request.QueryString.HasValue
            )
            {
                var token = context.Request.QueryString.Value
                    .Split('&')
                    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Contains("access_token"))?.Split('=')[1];
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
                {
                    context.Request.Headers.Add(
                        "Authorization", 
                        new[] { $"Bearer {token}" }
                    );
                }
            }
            await next.Invoke();
        });
        // END BEARER TOKEN MIDDLEWARE -----------------------------------------------

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        ...

    }
```

Obviously this isn't the best scenario from a security point of view, so ensure that your api is over https and take care to encrypt or totally avoid requests log.

Comment: As you say: I would like to use out-of-the-box solutions from professionals for authentication. But you have to do with what you get.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the SignalR JavaScript client, you can provide a method which will return an access token, which will be included in the client's requests as a Bearer token. This *should* work regardless of the transport method used (though I haven't tried it myself)

Example from the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?#configure-bearer-authentication):

```
let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/myhub", {
        accessTokenFactory: () => {
            // Get and return the access token.
            // This function can return a JavaScript Promise if asynchronous
            // logic is required to retrieve the access token.
        }
    })
    .build();
```

Comment: This is the way I set the token. But in the "Authentication and authorization" page of the docs it states: "When using WebSockets and Server-Sent Events, the token is transmitted as a query string parameter." So I have to handle them on the backend.

Comment: Ah, indeed. Looks like this is something the Azure App Service's built-in authorization feature can handle. (It's also explicitly recommended _against_ by the OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token spec in [Section 5.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-5.3)...)